# SMPS output grounding (PE)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ground, grounding, chassis

I am designing an ultralow noise 5V/3A SMPS.

On the DC side, I see the ground (DC) is earthed (chassis ground) using a direct connection 0 ohm or using a Y capacitor. What are the differences between them and whats best for low noise on DC output?

On the positive side (DC) I also see that sometimes it's earthed (chassis ground) using a Y capacitor. Is it recommended to make this connection (if our goal is low noise on DC output)? Is 330 pF enough as a value for the Y cap?

Comment: Common mode or differential low noise?

Comment: Differential noise.

Comment: The capacitors you mention in your question only reduce common-mode noise.

Comment: Thats fine . Our differential noise is under 1mV. Questions still stand , whats best for as DC ground connection and should we use the Y cap on the positive of DC ? (to reduce common mode noise)

Comment: Your target load and whether it is earthed or has imbalanced impedances to ground will dictate common-mode noise seen on the line and given that we don't know this it's hard to guess. Be aware that just putting CM capacitors on the output of your power supply may sometimes be NOT the best way - it might be that your target load will perform better with capacitors to ground on some of its nodes. There is no general answer to this.

Comment: target load is unknown. ( can be anything) .One solution (we discussed in house) is to have a switch on the DC ground that will "chose" betwen direct earthing (chassis earthing) or capacitor earthing (chassis earthing ). Still we are unsure if the capacitor on the positive is needed (we understand now that it will reduce common mode noise).

Comment: Not knowing the target load is a problem and on some applications I have had to get a supplier to remove common-mode capacitors on their SMPS offering so that I could effectively move them to the output lines of my target circuit. This was done to enable our target circuit to pass EMC tests without EMI currents passing through our circuit and causing problems.

Comment: Ok last clarification...when we added a CMC on the output of SMPS we seen an increase in DM noise...but I read its normal. My question is , does it make sense to have a CMC on the DC output even with negative/positive common mode caps ?

Comment: It can cause a slight increase in DM noise if the inductors are not perfectly balanced and the output capacitors are not perfectly matched. Personally I'd get rid of the CM choke. You can easily simulate the effects of course in micro-cap or LTSpice (both free) and this would become clear when you imbalanced the values.

Comment: Andy AKA , that makes a lot of sense...I would like to chose one of your comments as an answer since now its clear to me what I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Initial thoughts

Your target load and whether it is earthed or has imbalanced impedances to ground will dictate common-mode noise seen on the line and, given that we don't know this, it's hard to guess. Be aware that just putting CM capacitors on the output of your power supply may sometimes be NOT the best way - it might be that your target load will perform better with capacitors to ground on some of its nodes. There is no general answer to this.

### Not knowing the target load...

Not knowing the target load is a problem and on some applications I have had to get a supplier to remove common-mode capacitors on their SMPS offering so that I could effectively move them to the output lines of my target circuit. This was done to enable our target circuit to pass EMC tests without EMI currents passing through our circuit and causing problems.

### Adding CM chokes to the output can be a mixed blessing

It can cause a slight increase in DM noise if the inductors are not perfectly balanced and the output capacitors are not perfectly matched. Personally I'd get rid of the CM choke. You can easily simulate the effects of course in micro-cap or LTSpice (both free) and this would become clear when you imbalanced the values.